# global algebraic functions $\Gamma(T^{*}M)$ on the cotangent bundle of moduli space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

Let $X\colon$ smooth projective curve,
$\mathcal{M}\colon $ moduli space of semistable higgs bundle of rank $r$ and with fixed determinat $\xi$, and
$H\colon \mathcal{M}\rightarrow W=\oplus_{i=2}^{r} H^{0}(X,K_{X}^{\otimes i})$ be the Hitchin map.
$T^{*}M\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ cotangent bundle of stable vector bundle as an open subscheme.
$h$ denotes the restriction of $H$ to $T^{*}M$.

I'm reaing [the paper of Indranil Biswas, Tomas L. Gomez, V. Munoz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2961) and want to show the following Lemma,

> the natural map $\Gamma(W)\rightarrow \Gamma(T^{*}M)$ induced by $h$ is an isomorphism.

I already know that $\Gamma(W)\rightarrow \Gamma(\mathcal{M})$ is an isomorphism.

Let $\eta\in W$ be the generic point. Then, $H^{-1}(\eta)$ is smooth, and
$\operatorname{codim}(h^{-1}(\eta),H^{-1}(\eta))\geq 2$.
From this, the paper concludes that the Lemma holds.

But I don't know how to deduce and complete the proof. I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removing a closed subset of codimension $\geq 2$ on $\mathcal{M}$ doesn't change the ring of functions.